# In Yii can you return an HTTP error response in JSON instead of HTML/XML?

Tags: php, angularjs, http, yii2

If a user is attempting to access the REST api without proper credentials, my yii application throws the 401 error like this in my controller.php file:

```
throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('Access unavailable without access_token.', 401);
```

Which returns the error in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <name>Unauthorized</name><message>Access unavailable.</message>      
  <code>401</code>
  <status>401</status>
  <type>yii\web\UnauthorizedHttpException</type>
</response>
```

How to I return this error in JSON format ?

```
{
    "name": "Access unavailable.",
    "message": "You are not authorized.",
    "code": 0,
    "status": 401
}
```

My mobile app accessing this resource expects a JSON object.

Comment: I suggest your app actually use the status code. It's http first, json second. I mean, there could be 5xx error at some point, and then you won't be able to produce any json anyway. So handle status codes please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yii2 rest controller reacts on the "Accept" HTTP Header. If in this header is only "application/json" present, the answer from rest controller will be JSON

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this above the return or better in your custom __construct.

```
Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me.  Extend the `activeController` and i put it in `api\controllers\ActiveController.php`

```
namespace api\controllers;
class ActiveController extends yii\rest\ActiveController {

    public function behaviors() {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ]
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
}
```

then in my controller

```
use api\controllers\ActiveController;

class blablaController extends ActiveController
{
...
}
```

now on unauthorized i get a JSON instead of an XML

```
{"success":false,"data":{"name":"Unauthorized","message":"Your request was made with invalid credentials.","code":0,"status":401}}
```